# Including into a variable

Tags: php

You know how `print_r` accepts an optional 2nd parameter that if set to `true` will return the result instead of printing it?

I wish `include` accepted a 2nd parameter that would work the same way.

It doesn't so what are the available alternatives? How can I include a file into a variable?

Comment: **What** do you want it to return?

Comment: @delnan, The parsed content of a specified file.

Comment: The literal contents of the file? An abstract syntax tree from the code in the file? Bytecode?

Comment: @delnan, `echo $result` should do the same as `include "foo.php"` when `$result` holds the returned value in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) will do that for you:

```
ob_start();
include "file.php";
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

After ob_start() everything echoed is captured, and ob_get_clean() is used to retrieve the captured data.

You can even do an `include2` function like this:

```
function include2($file) {
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
include2("file.php"); // return all printed values instead of really printing them
```

As noted by @ircmaxell, this `include2` function does not behave exactly the same as `include` since the scope of the include changes (from global to the function's scope). So this could potentially break things if you rely on the global scope.

Comment: Not much overhead, since you output also goes to an output-buffer first and sent to the client in chunks. That is why you need to call flush() if you want to send output right away.

Comment: I would say that this has very little cost; but the better answer would be a benchmark on your own application

Comment: The correct is ob_get_clean()! ob_end_clean() only returns true or false. @user576875: please, correct your post!

Comment: The only problem (Well, not a problem, just needs to be noted) with the function, is that it does not behave exactly the same since the scope of the include changes (from global to the function's scope).  So this could potentially break things if you rely on the global scope.  But you shouldn't anyway, so no big deal!

Comment: @user576875: The code is correct but the text is still wrong. Please, fix it so it will be a neat help-post and so I can +1 it up :)

Comment: "After ob_start() everything echoed is captured, and ob_end_clean() is used to retrieve the captured data.", but whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for #5 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

return stuff from a script.

include handles a return value from the script.

Comment: The return value and the output are very different things.

Comment: for sure but I can't help but think OP is in the need of a rewrite of his scripts.